# Fork and Stack creation in memory

Tags: unix, process, fork

I am very curious about this..
I heard someone saying that when fork () is called and its value is stored in a variable p with data type pid_t then if the value in p is 
-1 process cannot be created
0 process created in main functions stack
1 process created with own stack allocated in memory
I dont see any of this on the internet.
Could anyone help me
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fork() creates a new, independent process by making a copy of the current one, executing exactly at the point the original process is. A return value of -1 means that the new process couldn't be created.

If the return value is positive, that means that this process is the original master and that return value is the new process' process ID (pid). Inside the new process, the return from fork() is 0. That's how you can take different actions in the original and new processes.

See, for example, http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork .

Comment: Okay i got that but i heard my professor saying that when fork returns 0 it means that a new process is created and its stack is in main's stack but when 1 is returned the new process has its own stack but i dont see this anywhere on the internet. So is that statement true? Thanks

Comment: Both processes are completely independent and have their own stack, although since the new process is a copy of the original, right after the fork the new one's stack looks just like the original's. But the new process' stack is never in the original's stack, their memory space is totally separate. The fork return value always just tells you which copy you're in, or if no copy was made.

Comment: Oh my god that means my answer to the external was totally wrong. Therfore a stack is always created when a process is created.